# Why is this descender displaying below another character in Safari?

Tags: html, css, text, fonts

[image]

Whenever I load the page on Safari (desktop or mobile), this paragraph element displays with the "y" descender displaying below the "r" in "Jeremy." I've never seen something like this before...it only happens in Safari, and it disappears the moment you click into the inspector or adjust the page in any way...

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Step 1 when it comes to questions like this is to create a [mcve] because just asking about a screenshot is not [asking a question people can actually answer](/help/how-to-ask). They can guess, but SO is not for posting guesses.

Comment: This would work except I don't think this type of error is something that could be caused by HTML or CSS. I'm wondering if it's a browser error and if anyone knows about it.

Comment: That is literally why you should make an mcve. It forces you to start with something that's broken, and remove things in small steps until things are suddenly not broken. Then you undo the last thing, confirm that breaks it again, and start removing other things, until you've reduced your problem to the absolute minimum amount of code, which others (and you) can then analyse properly.